# Entity Framework 4.3 Attaching an object from a parameter of an Action of a Controller

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

I have a situation where I have an object that is loaded back from a form to MVC controller via an action. We do not use FormCollection, but the one that use directly the class.

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult AjaxUpdate(Customer customer) { ...
```

The Customer object contain an object called customer which seem to be updated but when using SaveDatabase() on the context simply doesn't work.

To make it works I had to use in the action:

```
myDbContext.Customers.Attach(customer) 
//...Code here that set to the customer.SubObject a real object from the database so I am sure that the SubObject contain an id which is valid and the datacontext is aware of it...
myDbContext.Entry(customer).State = EntityState.Modified;
```

Still, I had an exception concerning the "Store update, insert, or delete statement affected an unexpected number of rows (0)" that I were able to remove by using:

```
Database.ObjectContext().Refresh(RefreshMode.ClientWins,customer);
```

So, to warp up my question, **why** do I have to Attach + change the state + call Refresh. Isn't there a better way to update an object that contain object that are referenced in an other table. I am using Code first Entity Framework (Poco object). Also, I do not like to use Refresh since it's hidden from my Databasecontext.

Comment: It looks like you have concurrency update problem. Do you have field with Timestamp attribute in class Customer?

Comment: Since it's a new class everything is string, but the ID which is the primary key which is an integer. The Country is virtual and it of type Country.

Comment: Do you also have the error when you remove the code which is hidden behind the comment? If not, it might be helpful to sketch this hidden code in more detail because it's probably important then. The need to use `Refresh` to get a working UPDATE of an object graph is "not normal".

Comment: The code in comment (hidden in this post) is a query to the subobject to get an instance of this subobject to the customer. This is done because the client can in a combo box select a new value and I load back the object from the database, assign it to customer (with the goal to have the FK of customer updated).

Comment: Are you using the same context `myDbContext` to get the subobject? Do you have a foreign key property for the subobject in the `Customer` class?

Comment: Yes the same DbContext is used and a foreign key property is used for the subobject.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've made a console test project with EF 4.3.1. The code is my guess what you mean with the commented line and your comments below the question (but my guess is probably wrong because the program doesn't reproduce your error):

You can copy the code into program.cs and add a reference to EF 4.3.1:

```
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Entity;

namespace EFUpdateTest
{
    public class Customer
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public int SubObjectId { get; set; }
        public SubObject SubObject { get; set; }
    }

    public class SubObject
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Something { get; set; }
    }

    public class CustomerContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Customer> Customers { get; set; }
        public DbSet<SubObject> SubObjects { get; set; }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int customerId = 0;
            int subObject1Id = 0;
            int subObject2Id = 0;
            using (var ctx = new CustomerContext())
            {
                // Create customer with subobject
                var customer = new Customer { Name = "John" };
                var subObject = new SubObject { Something = "SubObject 1" };
                customer.SubObject = subObject;
                ctx.Customers.Add(customer);

                // Create a second subobject, not related to any customer
                var subObject2 = new SubObject { Something = "SubObject 2" };
                ctx.SubObjects.Add(subObject2);

                ctx.SaveChanges();

                customerId = customer.Id;
                subObject1Id = subObject.Id;
                subObject2Id = subObject2.Id;
            }

            // New context, simulate detached scenario -> MVC action
            using (var ctx = new CustomerContext())
            {
                // Changed customer name
                var customer = new Customer { Id = customerId, Name = "Jim" };
                ctx.Customers.Attach(customer);

                // Changed reference to another subobject
                var subObject2 = ctx.SubObjects.Find(subObject2Id);
                customer.SubObject = subObject2;

                ctx.Entry(customer).State = EntityState.Modified;

                ctx.SaveChanges();
                // No exception here.
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This works without exception. The question is: What is different in your code which could cause the error?

**Edit**

To your comment that you don't have a foreign key property `SubObjectId` in the customer class: If I remove the property in the example program above I can reproduce the error.

The solution is to load the original subobject from the database before you change the relationship:

```
// Changed customer name
var customer = new Customer { Id = customerId, Name = "Jim" };
ctx.Customers.Attach(customer);

// Load original SubObject from database
ctx.Entry(customer).Reference(c => c.SubObject).Load();

// Changed reference to another subobject
var subObject2 = ctx.SubObjects.Find(subObject2Id);
customer.SubObject = subObject2;

ctx.Entry(customer).State = EntityState.Modified;

ctx.SaveChanges();
// No exception here.
```

Without a foreign key property you have an *Independent Association* which requires that the object *including all references* must represent the state in the database before you change it. If you don't set the reference of `SubObject` in `customer` EF assumes that the original state in the database is that customer does not refer to any subobject. The generated SQL for the UPDATE statement contains a WHERE clause like this:

```
WHERE [Customers].[Id] = 1 AND [Customers].[SubObject_Id] IS NULL
```

If the customer has a subobject in the DB `[SubObject_Id]` is *not* NULL, the condition is not fulfilled and the UPDATE does not happen (or happens for the "unexpected number of rows 0").

The problem does not occur if you have a foreign key property (*Foreign Key Association*): The WHERE clause in this case is only:

```
WHERE [Customers].[Id] = 1
```

So, it doesn't matter what's the original value of `SubObject` and of `SubObjectId`. You can leave the values `null` and the UPDATE works nonetheless.

Hence, the alternative solution to loading the original subobject is to introduce a foreign key property in `Customer`:

```
public int SubObjectId { get; set; }
```

Or, in case the relationship is not required:

```
public int? SubObjectId { get; set; }
```

Comment: Thx for the example. I give you the +1. Let me compare. At the first look, I am doing exactly what you are doing. The only difference is that the subobject is taken from EF not with its PK but from a code (which is also unique in a different way). But, let me investigate more from what you gave me and I come back to you.

Comment: Alright, here is the big difference. You use the ID inside Customer for SubObjectID and I do not. If I check not the inner exception but the exception I see : "An error occurred while saving entities that do not expose foreign key properties for their relationships. The EntityEntries property will return null because a single entity cannot be identified as the source of the exception. Handling of exceptions while saving can be made easier by exposing foreign key properties in your entity types. See the InnerException for details."

Comment: @PatrickDesjardins: OK, I was assuming you had a FK property because you said so in your last comment under your question. I've removed it now and tested again. Result of this test is in the Edit section of my answer.

Comment: I do not have the exception once I have remove the Context. But still I can't save the SubObject which both seem to not update. If I profile the SQL I see the Update but the field of the subobject is not in the SQL... I will accept this answer and wrote another question. Thank you,